# Geonodes - ALL Boolean Intersecting edges

Tags: geometry-nodes

How could I select ALL the intersecting edges when I'm doing a boolean difference?
So how could I add the bottom edges to the selection?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Intersecting Edges' are the new geometry generated at the intersection of surfaces (not volumes).By that definition, you do have all the intersecting edges. If you mean all geometry in the cutter, would this do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I need.